# Database created in sqlcmd but missing in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sqlcmd

I created a database named `testbase` in `sqlcmd` in `SERVER\MSSQLSERVER`. However, I cannot access `SERVER\MSSQLSERVER`.

I also could not find `testbase` inside the server connection using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Appreciate any help / tips / hints.

Comment: Did you use the same user for both sqlcmd and ssms?

Comment: seeing your other question, are you sure you actually created the DB and didn't forget to end with a GO in SQLCMD?

Comment: I notice that actual I went into the wrong connection as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I went to the wrong connection. It should be `SERVER\MSQLSERVER` rather than `SERVER\MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: I can see how that might be confusing....